# NEXT Image: Shrinking inside flexbox with tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind-css, next-images

I am using NEXT Image component to Fit in with a flex box without shrinking. However, based on the content that is there in the other element, it keeps shrinking:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Image from 'next/image';
type Props = {
  imageUrl?: string;
  senderName: string;
  newMessageCount?: number;
  latestMessage: string;
};

export default function MessageBox({
  imageUrl,
  senderName,
  newMessageCount,
  latestMessage,
}: Props) {
  const isNewMessageDefined = newMessageCount ? true : false;
  const newMsgValue =
    latestMessage.length > 80
      ? `${latestMessage.slice(0, 80)}...`
      : latestMessage;
  return (
    <div className='flex w-full gap-2' aria-label='Funfuse-Message-Container'>
      <Image
        alt='Message Image'
        src={imageUrl ?? '/funfuse/avatar-02.jpg'}
        className='rounded-full shadow-lg shrink-0 shadow-indigo-500/50'
        height={80}
        width={80}
        objectFit='cover'
        objectPosition='center'
      />
      <div className='flex flex-col'>
        <div
          aria-label='Funfuse-Message-Header'
          className='flex flex-row items-center gap-2'>
          <h2 className='text-xl text-black'>{senderName ?? 'John Doe'}</h2>
          {isNewMessageDefined && (
            <div className='h-[1.2rem] w-[1.2rem] rounded-full relative bg-funfuse'>
              <label className='absolute text-xs text-white transform -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 top-1/2 left-1/2'>
                {newMessageCount}
              </label>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
        <div aria-label='Funfuse-Message-Body'>
          <label className='text-sm font-semibold text-gray-400'>
            {newMsgValue}
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Can someone help me identify how to prevent this issue as I always want my image to be of the size and never shrink. I tried using the property: `flex-shrink: 0` but that didn't work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another fix that worked for me in a similar case. I wrapped the `<Image />` component around a div with `position: relative;width:80px;height:80px`, removed `width` and `height` properties from the `<Image />` component and added `layout="fill"` instead.

So instead of this

```
<Image
  alt='Message Image'
  src={imageUrl ?? '/funfuse/avatar-02.jpg'}
  className='rounded-full shadow-lg shrink-0 shadow-indigo-500/50'
  height={80}
  width={80}
  objectFit='cover'
  objectPosition='center'
/>
```

You would have something like this

```
<div className="relative w-[80px] h-[80px]">
 <Image
   alt='Message Image'
   src={imageUrl ?? '/funfuse/avatar-02.jpg'}
   className='rounded-full shadow-lg shrink-0 shadow-indigo-500/50'
   layout="fill"
   objectFit='cover'
   objectPosition='center'
 />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

it may be because of the layout attribute in the default Image tag is responsive, it reduces its size when it reduces the width of the parent.

Set the layout fixed to keep the width of the image fixed.
Here you can read more about next/image: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image

```
 return (
<div className='flex w-full gap-2' aria-label='Funfuse-Message-Container'>
  <Image
    alt='Message Image'
    src={imageUrl ?? '/funfuse/avatar-02.jpg'}
    className='rounded-full shadow-lg shrink-0 shadow-indigo-500/50'
    height={80}
    layout="fixed"
    width={80}
    objectFit='cover'
    objectPosition='center'
  />
  <div className='flex flex-col'>
    <div
      aria-label='Funfuse-Message-Header'
      className='flex flex-row items-center gap-2'>
      <h2 className='text-xl text-black'>{senderName ?? 'John Doe'}</h2>
      {isNewMessageDefined && (
        <div className='h-[1.2rem] w-[1.2rem] rounded-full relative bg-funfuse'>
          <label className='absolute text-xs text-white transform -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 top-1/2 left-1/2'>
            {newMessageCount}
          </label>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
    <div aria-label='Funfuse-Message-Body'>
      <label className='text-sm font-semibold text-gray-400'>
        {newMsgValue}
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

);

Comment: Hey Thanks but I actually tried this too. It had no effect

Comment: @ShivamSahil did you resolve this? same problem here.

Comment: Nope used some hack to fix it at that time don't remember exactly now. Maybe `object-fit: cover; object-position: center;` something along those lines

Answer (score 0):

Agree with answer from @georgekpc, you need to wrap the Image in a container

From the docs

> The parent element must assign position: "relative", position:
> "fixed", or position: "absolute" style.

However, the `layout` prop is now deprecated and you need to use the `fill` prop as true.

```
    <div className="relative h-[56px] w-[56px]">
      <Image
        className="h-14 w-14 rounded-full"
        src={author.profileImageUrl}
        alt="Profile Image"
        fill={true}
      />
    </div>
```

https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image

https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image#fill